# Only evaluate non-zero values of tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training to train a Neural Network using Keras and I am using my own metric function as the loss function. The reason for this is that the actual values in the test set have a lot of NaN values. Let me give an example of the actual values in the test set:

```
12
NaN
NaN
NaN
8
NaN
NaN
3
```

In the preprocessing of my data, I replaced all the NaN values with zeros, so the above example contains zeros on each NaN row.

The Neural Network produces an output like this:

```
14
12
9
9
8
7
6
3
```

I only want to calculate the root mean squared error between the non-zero values. So for the example above, it should only calculate the RMSE for rows 1, 5 and 8. To do this, I created the following function:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

[...]

def evaluation_metric(y_true, y_pred):

y_true = y_true[np.nonzero(y_true)]
y_pred = y_pred[np.nonzero(y_true)]

error = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
return error
```

When you test the  function by hand, by feeding the actual values from the test set and an output from the neural network that is initialized with random weights, it works well an produces an error value. I am able to optimize the weights using an Evolutionary approach, and I am able to optimize this error measure by adjusting the weights of the network.

Now, I want to train the network with `evaluation_metric` as the loss function using the `model.compile` function from Keras. When I run:

```
model.compile(loss=evaluation_metric, optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=[evaluation_metric])
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

I think this has to do with the usage of `np.nonzero`. Since I am working with Keras, I should probably use a function of the Keras Backend, or using something like tf.cond to check for the non zero values of y_true.

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**

The code works after applying the following fix:

```
def evaluation_metric(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true = y_true * (y_true != 0) 
    y_pred = y_pred * (y_true != 0)

    error = root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    return error
```

Along with the following function for calculating the RMSE of a tf object:

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `y_true = y_true * (y_true != 0) ` multiplies the values by 0 if they are 0, otherwise by 1, or in other words, it does nothing and therefore can be removed

Comment: Also, I'm getting `TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type bool that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.` when using `y_pred = y_pred * (y_true != 0)` in a custom loss function.

Comment: I used `y_pred = y_pred * tf.cast((y_true != 0), 'float32')` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed the problem lies in using `numpy` function. Here is a quick fix:

```
def evaluation_metric(y_true, y_pred):

    y_true = y_true * (y_true != 0) 
    y_pred = y_pred * (y_true != 0)

    error = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    return error
```

Comment: Your fix worked when I also adapted the RMSE error measure in the following way, so Keras can work with it:
I replaced 
`sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))`

with `def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))`

Comment: Consider (5,1) as pred (1,2) as true and (0,1) as the mask. The correct result would be rmse=1. But this solution would give you rmse=sqrt(0.5)!

Comment: This actually a good property of this loss - each data point has exactly the same influence - and the number of `na`s in data point is not affecting actual training process.

Answer (score -1):

I would write the metric in tensorflow on my own like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0]).astype(np.float32)
pred = np.random.randn(8).astype(np.float32)
gt = np.random.randn(8).astype(np.float32)

data_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
pred_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(pred)
gt_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(gt)

expected = np.sqrt(((gt[data != 0] - pred[data != 0]) ** 2).mean())


def nonzero_mean(gt_op, pred_op, data_op):
    mask_op = 1 - tf.cast(tf.equal(data_op, 0), tf.float32)

    actual_op = ((gt_op - pred_op) * mask_op)**2
    actual_op = tf.reduce_sum(actual_op) / tf.cast(tf.count_nonzero(mask_op), tf.float32)
    actual_op = tf.sqrt(actual_op)
    return actual_op

with tf.Session() as sess:

    actual = sess.run(nonzero_mean(gt_op, pred_op, data_op))

print actual, expected
```

The `y_true != 0` is not possible in plain Tensorflow. Not sure, if keras does some magic here.

Comment: Actually it does! I got my metric working by replacing the 
`sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))`

with `def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))`

Thanks for your suggestion, however!

Comment: Then it is Keras magic. But mathematically it is wrong. You do *not* get the mean of the quantity you are interested in. You get something smaller than the mean (depending on how much zeros are there). Compare what you get to my reference implementation in numpy.

Comment: What is gt_op in your implementation? In my implementation I have `y_true` which is the actual output values with the zeros (`data` in your implementation?) and I have `y_pred` which is the predicted output by Keras (`pred_op` or `gt_op`?)